# How to transform 6 DOF motion

Tags: coordinate-systems

## Question

Suppose there are two coordinate system A and B with gyro or vision sensor. Coordinate B is rigidly mounted on coordinate A with rotation $R$ and translation $t$ expressed in global coordinate system.

When we get the 6 DOF motion $(v_x, v_y, v_z, w_x, w_y, w_z)^T_A$ from the sensors from coordinate A, what signal the sensors in system B will catch?

Each $v_m$ and $w_m$ means translation and angular velocity.

I want something like following equation:
$$(v_x, v_y, v_z, w_x, w_y, w_z)^T_B=f((v_x, v_y, v_z, w_x, w_y, w_z)^T_A,R,t)$$

### Sub-question

(I read following description from a paper.)

Suppose there are a sensor mounted on coordinate system A.
When the sensor moves with translation $v_c = (v_x, v_y,v_z)^\top$ and rotation $w_c = (w_x, w_y, w_z)$, and there is a static point at $p = (X,Y,Z)^\top$ in the system A. Then, the relationship between the sensor motion and the observed points motion will be like:

$$\dot{p}=-v_c+w_c \times P$$

Could you introduce me any explanation about this topic?(including: Online text, PDF, Textbook)
Thank you.

Comment: Your degrees of freedom $(vx,vyvz,wx,wy,yz)$ don't make sense to me.
May be you mean something like $(v_x,v_y,v_z,w_x,w_y,w_z)$.
But anyway, what is the exact meaning of these?

Comment: Sorry for poor expression. I edited my question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ok, looks understandable now.